# RequestMiddlewares.php: new handling? (TYPO3 Extbase)

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-11.x

This used to work in TYPO3 9 and TYPO3 10 but is not working from me in TYPO3 11:

EXTDIR/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php

```
<?php
return [
    'frontend' => [
        'varioous/rest/mail-chimp-middleware' => [
            'target' => Varioous\Rest\MailChimpMiddleware::class,
            'before' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/eid',
                'typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I've looked at this description here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html but I can't find the problem. The code is from this example: https://various.at/news/typo3-tipps-und-tricks-psr-15-mideelware-am-beispiel-mailchimp-webhook and has been adjusted to a custom made extension that has been working fine with TYPO3 9 and TYPO3 10. The particular extension belongs to the customer and I am not permitted to post it here. It is configured exactly as the mailchimp extension is in the how-to and I am sure the author used that how-to as a reference. As it seems, the mailchimp extension from the TER stopped using middleware - so I can't use the current version as a reference to fix my problem.

With this temporary workaround it's working fine:

```
<?php
return [
    'frontend' => [
        'varioous/rest/mail-chimp-middleware' => [
            'target' => Varioous\Rest\MailChimpMiddleware::class,
            'before' => [
                # 'typo3/cms-frontend/eid',
                # 'typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

How do I have to adjust the references to 'typo3/cms-frontend/eid' and 'typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe' for TYPO3 11? When I look up HTTP Middlewares (PSR-15) in the Configuration BackEnd module I can find them in the frontend category:

> - typo3/cms-frontend/eid = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\EidHandler
> - typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\TypoScriptFrontendInitialization

**FYI Further description of the Problem:**

Once the extension is activated, ALL local extbase extensions stop working. For Example:

> #1316104317 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception
>
> The default controller for extension "News" and plugin "Pi1" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.

Of course there is nothing wrong with the news extension. I temporarily added a debug output in the file typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Web/RequestBuilder.php

```
protected function loadDefaultValues()
{
  $configuration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
  print_r($configuration);
```

When the extension with the middleware is activated, the value "controllerConfiguration" in the array returned from the ConfigurationManager is empty (for all local extensions).

Comment: Have you tried with one "before" only? The second one seems superfluous. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I did with either one of them alone, but it didn't help

Comment: The target is missing the \-prefix for the namespace. Just to rule out that this is just a misspelling here and perhaps exists in the code as well and creates a strange, yet undiscovered parsing error leading to that exception.

Comment: I've also changed that before in the customers extension (sorry for forgetting to mention it)

Comment: Am I looking for the problem in the wrong place? Could it be, that the middleware itself is messing up the TypoScriptFrontendInitialization?

Comment: Regarding my last post: even if I change the process function of the middleware interface to this one line:

      "return $handler->handle($request);"

I get the same result.

Comment: The extension creates instances of repositories in the MiddlewareInterface. When I remove those, the error disappears.
I've tried with injection in __construct() and with GeneralUtility::makeInstance(...), but it doesn't seem to be working anymore. Creating an instance of ErrorController for example is OK though.

Comment: Not sure, what you are doing in your middleware, but the concept intends fast responses for simple logic. Bootstrapping the whole TYPO3 (TS-parsing, Extbase) is the opposite. Maybe, you can simplify your database interactions and get rid of extbase/repositories an TS.

Comment: I think you're right Julian. I don't know much about middleware, but from what I've learned so far, it's not intended to be what's done in that extension.

Comment: I fear that the question I've asked isn't solvable because it seems that the problem is not what I thought it was. What I've learned so far is, that until TYPO3 10 it was possible to create an instance of a repository before tsfe middleware, but since TYPO3 11 that seems impossible (it works after tsfe). Also I haven't figured out, why the extension is doing that kind of computing there. I kinda get what middleware can do, but I fail to see the benefit in that special case. Sorry for bothering you guys.